# Replace "/" by "\/" in a string Perl

Tags: regex, perl, text, scripting

Hello everyone !

#### Text

I have a little problem in my script. I would like to replace the `/` in a variable by a `\/`. Here is an explanation :

I have a variable :

```
$LAN = GigabitEthernet0/0.20
```

But when i use this variable in a **regex** the `/` is a problem. So I would like to change `GigabitEthernet0/0.20` into `GigabitEthernet0\/0.20`.

I tried with this : `$LAN =~ s/FIND/REPLACE/ig;` but it doesn't work due to all the `/`. I also tried with `$LAN =~ m///\//ig;`

#### Clarification

I'm doing the command `show arp` on a router. Here is the format of the result :

`Internet  192.168.1.1         34   99gg.zz23.atx2  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0.20`

I use a regex to extract the IP Address of an equipment : `(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+).*ARPA\s+$LAN`, obviously it doesn't match the `GigabitEthernet 0/0.20` because of the `/`. That's why I want to turn it into `\/`.

Thanks by advance **:)**

If you have other advice for my regex, don't hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quotemeta()` function will take a string and return it so that all the special characters used by the regex engine are correctly escaped.

eg.

```
$lan = quotemeta('GigabitEthernet0/0.20');
```

`$lan` is now `GigabitEthernet0\/0\.20`

Comment: AChichi, you could also use `\Q` and `\E` in your regexp instead of `quotemeta`, like so:  `/(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+).*ARPA\s+\Q$LAN\E/`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to escape all slashes that appear in your regular expression. So when you have the following where FIND is / and replace is \/

```
s/FIND/REPLACE/ig
```

you can't just put them in as is - you need to escape them. And you need to escape the escape backslash too. So it becomes

```
s/\//\\\//ig
```

which looks pretty hideous and is known as [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

But you don't need to do it that way as you can change what character is used to separate  in s/// or m// etc... Like this example, although you still need to escape the backslash.

```
s%/%\\/%ig
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you